# modify subpackage in django

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am running into a problem that I need to change a subpakcage of a big package in django. the big package, lets say foo, includes many subpackages, and I want to modify one of them, lets say bar. 
After weighing many options, I decide to dynamically change sys.modules when my django project starts. What i do is like this:

```
INSTALLED_APP=(...)
import sys, myproject.mybar #mybar is the the modified version
sys.modules['foo.bar']=myproject.mybar
```

This works fine in most cases, and whenever "from foo.bar import x,y,z" happens, it can be redirected to myproject.mybar. However, somewhere in the foo package, there is an import syntax like

```
import foo.bar.x
user = foo.bar.x.get_user(request)
```

This causes a "'module' object has no attribute" exception. Mybar package does have x module and get_user() method, and I am not sure why this happened. Anyone can help me to point me out what i miss here, also any suggestion to do what I am trying to achieve (modifying a subpackage) in a more pythonic and djangonic way?

P.S. the foo package is really big, and I dont want to include all of it in myproject.
Thank for your help in advance Python community ( :

Comment: Are you modifying Django code?

Comment: No. I am modifying a subpackage in a third party package.

Comment: Seems like you should fork the project, modify what you want, and install your version to Django application? Trying to dependency inject/mock a particular submodule within a large third-party application seems like a terrible idea (because of exactly the error you are getting: how do you know how the `__init__.py`'s are defined (which is likely why you're getting this error)? How do you know how the package imports its own stuff?).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are getting an `AttributeError` because somewhere in the package you're monkey-patching, it has an `__init__.py` that `imports` functions and classes from the module you edited. And then elsewhere in the package, it's attempting to use those functions and classes as attributes of the module.

This, in my opinion, is an example of why it would be a terrible idea to modify `sys.path` in order to inject a particular replacement module in as a dependency for a large, third-party package. In addition, what happens when this package gets updated in the future?

It seems to me that a much easier solution would be to 1) fork the project (depending on the license), 2) make your modifications, 3) set upstream to the original project (so you can still receive updates), and 4) install your forked version.

In this way, you have a much smaller problem: when the package imports its own stuff, you only have to worry that the code you've edited behaves appropriately (which is why you should also **add a test case for your edits and run all of the tests that the package supplies**).